# Join on one of two tables, depending on outcome of a conditional statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT S.PRODUCTNAME AS PRODUCTNAME,
T.TARGET AS TARGETVALUE,
SUM(S.AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT,
COUNT(S.PRODUCTNAME) AS VOLUME
FROM #SALES S
INNER JOIN 

-- Here it all goes south
-- IF (some condition)
-- TABLE1
-- ELSE
-- TABLE2
```

So it's pretty clear as to what I'm trying to achieve, if a certain condition is met, join on TABLE1 otherwhise, join on TABLE2. Though I know the syntax isn't correct and I'm not even sure this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join` and then choosing the right value in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT S.PRODUCTNAME AS PRODUCTNAME,
       COALESCE(T1.TARGET, T2.TARGET) AS TARGETVALUE,
       SUM(S.AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT, COUNT(S.PRODUCTNAME) AS VOLUME
FROM #SALES S LEFT JOIN 
     Table1 t1
     ON (some condition) LEFT JOIN
     Table2 t2
     ON (NOT (some condition))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the query like this:

```
if (condition)

SELECT S.PRODUCTNAME AS PRODUCTNAME,
T.TARGET AS TARGETVALUE,
SUM(S.AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT,
COUNT(S.PRODUCTNAME) AS VOLUME
FROM #SALES S
INNER JOIN TABLE1 

else

SELECT S.PRODUCTNAME AS PRODUCTNAME,
T.TARGET AS TARGETVALUE,
SUM(S.AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT,
COUNT(S.PRODUCTNAME) AS VOLUME
FROM #SALES S
INNER JOIN TABLE2
```

or you can use the dynamic SQL like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT S.PRODUCTNAME AS PRODUCTNAME,
    T.TARGET AS TARGETVALUE,
    SUM(S.AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT,
    COUNT(S.PRODUCTNAME) AS VOLUME
    FROM #SALES S
    INNER JOIN ' + CASE WHEN yourcondition THEN N'TABLE1 t' ELSE N'TABLE2 t' END
  + N' ON S.ID = t.ID';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Join with both tables, use case to select which field to expose.

```
select  S.PRODUCTNAME AS PRODUCTNAME,
        case when <condition> then t1.TARGET else t2.target end AS TARGETVALUE,
        SUM(S.AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT,
        COUNT(S.PRODUCTNAME) AS VOLUME
from    #SALES S
left join #Table1 t1
    on  t1.key = s.key
left join #Table2 t2
    on  t2.key = s.key;
```

I'm showing outer joins on the assumption that when the condition specifies T1 then T2 probably won't join at all and vice versa.